# jQuery slider range with HighCharts y-Axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to add a jQuery slider range bar on a HighCharts line chart to zoom in/out vertically. 
Here is how I have done this

```js
var ymax = 0.0;
var pSliderUnit = 0;
$(function() {
  $('#lineChart').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'line',
      zoomType: 'xy'
    },
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime',
      reversed: true
    },
    yAxis: [{
        events: {
          afterSetExtremes: function(e) {
            $("#pSliderBar").slider("values", 0, e.min);
            $("#pSliderBar").slider("values", 1, e.max);
          }
        },
        minRange: 1,
        showEmpty: false,
        labels: {
          format: '{value}'
        },
        title: {
          text: '\xB5g/m\xB3'
        },
        plotLines: []
      },
      {
        events: {
          afterSetExtremes: function(e) {
            $("#pSliderBar").slider("values", 0, e.min);
            $("#pSliderBar").slider("values", 1, e.max);
          }
        },
        minRange: 1,
        showEmpty: false,
        labels: {
          format: '{value}'
        },
        title: {
          text: 'mtr/sec'
        },
        opposite: true,
        plotLines: []
      },
      {
        events: {
          afterSetExtremes: function(e) {
            $("#pSliderBar").slider("values", 0, e.min);
            $("#pSliderBar").slider("values", 1, e.max);
          }
        },
        minRange: 1,
        showEmpty: false,
        labels: {
          format: '{value}'
        },
        title: {
          text: 'degrees'
        },
        plotLines: []
      },
    ],
    series: [{
        type: 'spline',
        name: 'Value 1',
        yAxis: 0,
        tooltip: {
          valueSuffix: '\xB5g/m\xB3'
        },
        data: [
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 20, 0), 20.4],
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 30, 0), 17.6],
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 40, 0), 18.8],
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 50, 0), 18.9]
        ]
      },
      {
        type: 'spline',
        name: 'Value 2',
        yAxis: 0,
        tooltip: {
          valueSuffix: '\xB5g/m\xB3'
        },
        data: [
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 20, 0), 11.2],
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 30, 0), 10.5],
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 40, 0), 11.2],
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 50, 0), 10.9]
        ]
      },
      {
        type: 'spline',
        name: 'Value 3',
        yAxis: 0,
        tooltip: {
          valueSuffix: '\xB5g/m\xB3'
        },
        data: [
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 20, 0), 5.71],
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 30, 0), 5.77],
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 40, 0), 5.69],
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 50, 0), 5.91]
        ]
      },
      {
        type: 'spline',
        name: 'Value 4',
        yAxis: 0,
        tooltip: {
          valueSuffix: '\xB5g/m\xB3'
        },
        data: [
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 20, 0), 3.07],
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 30, 0), 3.04],
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 40, 0), 3.03],
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 50, 0), 3.03]
        ]
      },
      {
        type: 'spline',
        name: 'Wind Speed',
        yAxis: 1,
        tooltip: {
          valueSuffix: 'mtr/sec'
        },
        data: [
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 20, 0), 0.5],
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 30, 0), 0.4],
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 40, 0), 0.2],
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 50, 0), 0.1]
        ]
      },
      {
        type: 'spline',
        name: 'Wind Direction',
        yAxis: 2,
        tooltip: {
          valueSuffix: 'degrees'
        },
        data: [
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 20, 0), 170.0],
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 30, 0), 90.0],
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 40, 0), 130.0],
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 50, 0), 65.0]
        ]
      }
    ]
  }, function(chart) {
    $("#pSliderBar").slider({
      range: true,
      orientation: "vertical",
      min: chart.yAxis[pSliderUnit].min,
      max: chart.yAxis[pSliderUnit].max,
      values: [chart.yAxis[pSliderUnit].min, chart.yAxis[pSliderUnit].max],
      slide: function(event, ui) {
        chart.yAxis[pSliderUnit].setExtremes(ui.values[0], ui.values[1])
      }
    });
  });
  $('#selectSliderUnit').change(function() {
    console.log("value:" + this.value);
    pSliderUnit = this.value;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td width="95%">
      <div id="lineChart" style="min-width: 600px; height: 500px;"></div>
    </td>
    <td width="5%" valign="top" align="center">
      <select id="selectSliderUnit" style="width: 20px;">
        <option value="0">ug/m^3</option>
        <option value="1">mtr/sec</option>
        <option value="2">degrees</option>
      </select><br><br>
      <div id="pSliderBar" style="height: 400px;"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

but there are some issues, it does not seem to be working correctly.
It needs to refresh the slider ranges on select change. 
Sometimes it throws `'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggleClass' of undefined'` exception, when I hide the lines.
Another problem is when zooming in slider goes back to top/bottom.
Can someone please help?

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rishad/9aqnq71n/)**

Thanks in advance

Comment: `it does not seem to be working correctly` What is the expected behaviour and what is the current behaviour?

Comment: It needs to refresh the slider range on select change.

Comment: @Codeer Thank you sir, you asked the question like an 'expert' but no response since then

Comment: Even with the answer in your comment, I cannot understand what is not working for you.

Comment: I have updated the question, there is a <select> on top of the slider which changes the yAxis but it is not updating the slider range after the change.

Comment: @AL̲̳I Your answer didn't clear the question up, like ewolden mentioned above. Also, I'd prefer not to respond with an answer when I didn't have the time to sit down for it yet. Knowing that probably more people would want some clarification, I already asked for it as it could take time from people to answer/edit/elaborate. No need to call me out like that while I only intended on helping you.

Comment: @Codeer Apologies, I did not mean to disrespect you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues that result in this not being a smooth slider.

1. You are not refreshing the slider after you have changed unit, the slider is initialized when the chart is loaded in the callback, but never called again. So `min`, `max`, `values` and `slide`, all use the initial settings. [API REF](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#chart)
2. You have set [`minRange: 1`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.minRange) for all 3 series, this does not work well for the second series which has a total range less than 1 and causes the slider to behave erratically.
3. You have **not** set `startOnTick` and `endOnTick` `false`, this causes the chart to jump from tick to tick.

To solve these issues, I made a function for the slider, that is called every time you select another option. I set minRange to 0.1 in the second series, and I set the step of the slider explicitly. I also disabled startOnTick and endOnTick.

```js
var ymax = 0.0;
var pSliderUnit = 0;
$(function() {
  var chart = Highcharts.chart('lineChart', {
    chart: {
      type: 'line',
      zoomType: 'xy'
    },
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime',
      reversed: true
    },
    yAxis: [{
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: false,
        events: {
          afterSetExtremes: function(e) {
            $("#pSliderBar").slider("values", [e.min, e.max]);
          }
        },
        minRange: 1,
        showEmpty: false,
        labels: {
          format: '{value}'
        },
        title: {
          text: '\xB5g/m\xB3'
        },
        plotLines: []
      },
      {
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: false,
        events: {
          afterSetExtremes: function(e) {
            $("#pSliderBar").slider("values", [e.min, e.max]);
          }
        },
        minRange: 0.1,
        min: 0,
        max: 1,
        showEmpty: false,
        labels: {
          format: '{value}'
        },
        title: {
          text: 'mtr/sec'
        },
        opposite: true,
        plotLines: []
      },
      {
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: false,
        events: {
          afterSetExtremes: function(e) {
            $("#pSliderBar").slider("values", [e.min, e.max]);
          }
        },
        minRange: 1,
        showEmpty: false,
        labels: {
          format: '{value}'
        },
        title: {
          text: 'degrees'
        },
        plotLines: []
      },
    ],
    series: [{
        type: 'spline',
        name: 'Value 1',
        yAxis: 0,
        tooltip: {
          valueSuffix: '\xB5g/m\xB3'
        },
        data: [
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 20, 0), 20.4],
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 30, 0), 17.6],
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 40, 0), 18.8],
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 50, 0), 18.9]
        ]
      },
      {
        type: 'spline',
        name: 'Value 2',
        yAxis: 0,
        tooltip: {
          valueSuffix: '\xB5g/m\xB3'
        },
        data: [
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 20, 0), 11.2],
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 30, 0), 10.5],
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 40, 0), 11.2],
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 50, 0), 10.9]
        ]
      },
      {
        type: 'spline',
        name: 'Value 3',
        yAxis: 0,
        tooltip: {
          valueSuffix: '\xB5g/m\xB3'
        },
        data: [
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 20, 0), 5.71],
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 30, 0), 5.77],
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 40, 0), 5.69],
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 50, 0), 5.91]
        ]
      },
      {
        type: 'spline',
        name: 'Value 4',
        yAxis: 0,
        tooltip: {
          valueSuffix: '\xB5g/m\xB3'
        },
        data: [
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 20, 0), 3.07],
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 30, 0), 3.04],
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 40, 0), 3.03],
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 50, 0), 3.03]
        ]
      },
      {
        type: 'spline',
        name: 'Wind Speed',
        yAxis: 1,
        tooltip: {
          valueSuffix: 'mtr/sec'
        },
        data: [
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 20, 0), 0.5],
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 30, 0), 0.4],
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 40, 0), 0.2],
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 50, 0), 0.1]
        ]
      },
      {
        type: 'spline',
        name: 'Wind Direction',
        yAxis: 2,
        tooltip: {
          valueSuffix: 'degrees'
        },
        data: [
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 20, 0), 170.0],
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 30, 0), 90.0],
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 40, 0), 130.0],
          [Date.UTC(2018, 4, 14, 16, 50, 0), 65.0]
        ]
      }
    ]
  }, Slider)

  function Slider(chart, pSliderUnit) {
    if (typeof pSliderUnit == 'undefined') {
      pSliderUnit = 0
    }
    $("#pSliderBar").slider({
      range: true,
      orientation: "vertical",
      min: Math.round(chart.yAxis[pSliderUnit].getExtremes().min * 100) / 100,
      max: Math.round(chart.yAxis[pSliderUnit].getExtremes().max * 100) / 100,
      step: (chart.yAxis[pSliderUnit].getExtremes().max  - chart.yAxis[pSliderUnit].getExtremes().min) / 100,
      values: [Math.round(chart.yAxis[pSliderUnit].getExtremes().min * 100) / 100, Math.round(chart.yAxis[pSliderUnit].getExtremes().max * 100) / 100],
      slide: function(event, ui) {
        chart.yAxis[pSliderUnit].setExtremes(ui.values[0], ui.values[1], true, false)
      }
    });
  };

  $('#selectSliderUnit').change(function() {
    console.log("value:" + this.value);
    Slider(chart, this.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td width="95%">
      <div id="lineChart" style="min-width: 600px; height: 500px;"></div>
    </td>
    <td width="5%" valign="top" align="center">
      <select id="selectSliderUnit" style="width: 20px;">
 <option value="0">ug/m^3</option><option value="1">mtr/sec</option><option value="2">degrees</option>
 </select><br><br>
      <div id="pSliderBar" style="height: 400px;"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

There is one more issue that I can't figure out of, when you set max slider for the first time without changing which option you are adjusting, it jumps.

**Working example:** https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/9aqnq71n/4/

Comment: Thanks for the amendments in the code, much appreciated. There are still some issue, one you mentioned also when I set the default extremes, the slider does not work. Thanks